# Launching a PUT or POST request after scanning QR Code

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, zbar-sdk

All the examples I see simply direct you to the url encoded in the QR code.  Is there an android library that can decode the url and submit a PUT to update a backend?  I'm looking at zxing and zbar but haven't found any sample code for that yet.  Thanks

Comment: ZXing let's you call the scanner via Intent, so you can use the URL returned from the Intent to update whatever you want on your backend.  There's no reason for any library to implement the functionality you're asking for as it's very specific and not a common use case, but it shouldn't be that hard to do yourself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are certainly libraries that will get the contents, the URL, from a QR code. That's 95% of the work. Issuing a `PUT` to a URL in Java is a few lines of code using `java.net.URL` and related classes. You could use Commons HttpClient if you liked its API better. So, yes, but it will naturally be a matter of using right tools for the two parts of the work.